# How to group the keys of JSON file on select options?

Tags: reactjs

I have a JSON (on JS file) :

```
const data =
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Foo",
        "year": "18"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Foo",
        "year": "16"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Foo",
        "year": "20"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Bar",
        "year": "15"
    }
]
export default data;
```

I want display a select with just 2 options "Foo" and "Bar"

```
import data from './data';

const SelectComponent = () => {

return (
<>
<Select>
      {data
        .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
        .map(({ id, name }) => (
          <option key={id} value={name}>
            {name}
          </option>
        ))}
    </Select>
</>
);
}

export default SelectComponent;
```

But my code return 3 options "Foo" and 1 option "Bar", how to group "Foo" on 1 option please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a set to keep track of the unique options and only render those.

```js
import data from "./data";


function getUniqueOptions(opts) {
  const optionSet = new Set();

  return opts
    .filter((item) => {
      if (!optionSet.has(item.name)) {
        optionSet.add(item.name);
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    })
    .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
}

const SelectComponent = () => {
  const uniqueOptions = getUniqueOptions(data);

  return (
    <>
      <Select>
        {uniqueOptions.map(({ id, name }) => (
          <option key={id} value={name}>
            {name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </>
  );
};

export default SelectComponent;
```

I moved the filtering code out of the component because the data is static in your case and putting it in the component means recalculating the array with each re-render.

Comment: For the moment they are static but I will call an API afterwards.

Comment: @gcbox999 that's fine, you can just move it back into the component then

Answer (score 0):

Turn the array of objects into a single object grouped by name first, with the duplicates removed:

```
const grouped = Object.fromEntries(
  data.map(item => [item.name, item.id])
);
```

```
<Select>
      {Object.entries(data)
        .map(([name, id]) => (
          <option key={id} value={name}>
            {name}
          </option>
        ))
      }
</Select>
```